# Laravel Google Login, Calendar and Drive multiple API integration

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-drive-api, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I have a question maybe useful for most of Laravel developers. 
I want to allow user to connect to one or more of these APIs:

- Google Login
- Google Calendar
- Google Drive

I have used Laravel Socialite so far, which provides clear connection to many social accounts. My issue is that through Socialite I have only one google Driver, while I need to address to different Google API from different buttons.

My .env data, connected to the config/services.php are:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=1.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=XXX
GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL=https://mysite/google/login_callback

GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID=2.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET=YYY
GOOGLE_CALENDAR_CALLBACK_URL=https://mysite/google/calendar_callback

GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID=3.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET=WWW
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CALLBACK_URL=https://mysite/google/drive_callback
```

Now, it is now clear to me how to manage multiple APIs from different buttons. Here some options:

1. Use Socialite with **unique credential entry point** (google_login) from Google Console Cloud and in the callback function into the Controller I differentiate different cases (login, calendar, drive...)
2. I create a different Google credential for each API into API section, I use Socialite only for login and I create/download separate package for Calendar, for Drive, etc...

So the main point is: multiple Google APIs in Laravel need to be applied with unique API credential and at Controller level I address to relative code using scopes or I have to create a separate API credential of each API, make the relevant .env keys and the manage all separately.

I hope to have been not to much blur.
thanks!

Comment: "multiple Google APIs in Laravel need to be applied with unique API credential" <-- why?  why not have the same credentials and one call back url

Comment: thanks Dalm that was my idea, but so in this case how to differentiate inside the same callback function the three different behaviors according to which is the scope? Or you meant to have THREE credentials on Google Cloud Platform and ONE callback?

Comment: There is meant to be one credential.  The user should authenticate to all of the scopes you need at once.  Or possibly authenticate to additional ones when you need.  Other wise your going to end up with three different access tokens and have to figer out which one gives you access to which api.

Answer (score 0):

With the socialite package, you can only do authentication. If you are developing for Calendar and Drive, I would suggest to use [google client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

```
 $client = new \Google_Client();
 $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
 $client->setSubject($email);
 $clien->addScope(['{scopes}']);
 $client->authorize();

 $client->get('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events');
```

Please also refer this document: [Event apis](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)
[Drive Apis](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference)

Comment: I would say that Socialite is not only for login, but only for ONE API at once. Unless I do not differentiate into the callback functions using an unique Google credential

Comment: Here for example (https://quantizd.com/google-drive-client-api-with-laravel/) it is using Socialite to login and google-api-client to connect to GDrive. I am wondering if so the combination of the two is the solution to apply the other Google APIs.

Comment: Yes, you should use Socialite for the authentication purpose. To call google apis, Google client library is the perfect fit and already used.

Comment: Hello again. thanks Shailesh. So as far as I understood: I need to have one credential key for all my APIs. Then manage through the controller callback when to redirect to a permission scopes window (i.e., only login) or to another (i.e. only google drive). right?

Comment: Yes correct. You need to ask the consent permission every time when you need access of Google service. If you need long term token, you should check offline access token.

Comment: Thanks once again Shailesh. My scope is to allow user to have different features: 1 is only login through Google (here permission window will ask user to accept my app to manage his name, email, etc...), 2 is to connect his Google Drive account (here permission window will ask user to accept my app to manage his google drive account), 3 is to connect to Google Calendar account...and so on. My doubt was on how to differentiate the different permission windows scopes using the same credentials